# How can I justify my skills against the required person specification?

Tags: faculty-application

I am applying for a faculty position. My academic career so far was very straightforward, which is well reflected in my CV. The job advertisement instructs that applicants should explain how they meet the requirements specified in the job description. One item in almost any faculty job is

- strong communication skills

I understand the importance of communication for a faculty position, but what can I say about my communication skills? What sort of evidence can justify my skills?

Comment: Invited talks, successful collaborations and leadership positions may be indicative of strong communication skills, particularly if substantiated in the reference letters and/or statements.

Comment: Write compelling research and teaching statements (thereby demonstrating your strong communication skills). Include the sentence “I have strong communication skills” in your cover letter.

Comment: @JeffE what is the point of stating “I have strong communication skills” without any tangible evidence? All applicants can write that (and they might be right, they think they have strong skills). How does it help the search committee?

Comment: @Googlebot - It shows that you are tailoring the cover letter to the specific job announcement, and it shows you believe you have strong communication skills. // I would include a specific example of how your strong communication skills have stood you in good stead.

Comment: @Googlebot Your compelling teaching and research statements are your evidence!  Or to turn your question around: Why should anyone believe your _description_ of your strong communication skills when they have a direct _example_ of your communication skills in their hands?

Answer (score 2):

"Strong communication skills" is included on virtually every faculty job posting because it is an important facet of faculty life.  A professor who can't or won't communicate effectively and respectfully can't work well with others - and academia is not a solitary profession. No department chair wants to run around cleaning up after a faculty member who has sent rude emails, alienated students or done anything else that will trigger a call from HR or the Dean's Office. No search committee wants to hire someone who will become a headache - they are looking for a new colleague. It would be a mistake to assume a well-written cover letter or research agenda is sufficient to demonstrate strong communication skills.

When applying for any job, it's important to highlight your skills and experiences in terms closely aligned to those in the posting.  Think about the types of communication a good faculty colleague and instructor would need: working collaboratively on committees and departmental programs, sharing lab space and other physical/equipment resources, teaching or supervising a wide range of students, engaging with other departments on campus, etc.  Give some thought to your communication style (written, oral, instructional, professional, etc.) and highlight skills that would make you a desirable colleague. Have you served in any leadership roles or on any committees, written or taught as part of a group, mentored students, helped solve a sticky situation, have good teaching evaluations that you can cite (especially those pertaining to your communication with students), etc? Your examples needn't be extensive or even strictly academic (maybe you were an RA or sold insurance as an undergrad or you've worked on a community or advocacy project?) but you've got to demonstrate that you understand the importance of communication in faculty success. It is - even in the sciences!